# How to Execute a PHP Script on a Host from a Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, php, url, connection

I have written a Java 2D game. It has local and global scores. Local scores were handled, but for global scores, I need to connect to a PHP script.

Script is simply like this:

```
http://myserver.com/highscore.php?action=submit&name=NAME&score=SCORE&
```

I can read scores with stream readers, but I can't send new scores to server. I've been looking into outputstreams, but I couldn't handle it.

I also checked this link: http://www.iismarconi.net/inside/materiale/java/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

But no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue, and if anyone needs a solution, I'm writing it here:

```
  HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(highscoreGlobal).openConnection();
  http.setRequestMethod("GET");     //You don't need to set this because HttpURLConnection works with GET in default, but anyway
  http.setReadTimeout( 15*1000);    //Timeout, 15 seconds.
  http.connect();

  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( http.getInputStream()));
```

And `reader.nextLine()` will give you the output. In my case, sql query returns 1 if insertion is successful.